# Keyword search, multiple tables, PHP and Mysql, Which Join to use?

Tags: php, mysql, search, join

I have 3 tables event, location, event_location. Event can have multiple locations.
Location table has lattitude, longitude, hasGeocode fields.

so for keywords "hello world"

a simple query to Event table becomes

```
Select * from event where keywords like '%hello%' OR keywords like '%world%'
```

but if if the user has entered their location then I want to include location table in this query as well, so that users can specify their choice of location, how do i do this?

so essentially 3 types of search queries

- just keywords
- keywords and location
- keywords, proximity and a location

I tried something like this -

```
   select * from event where keywords like '%hello%' OR
   keywords like '%world%' INNER JOIN location ON 
   location.location_id = event_location.location_id 
   INNER JOIN 
   event_location ON event_location.event_id = event.event_id
```

INNER JOINs mean event has to have one or more locations. If an event hasnt got any location it wont appear in search results. So please help me, how do I do this?

Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got your join syntax all mangled up. In any case, if inner joins are not cutting it, use outer joins. ;-)

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  event AS e
  LEFT JOIN event_location AS el ON el.event_id = e.event_id
  LEFT JOIN location       AS  l ON l.location_id = el.location_id
WHERE
  e.keywords LIKE '%hello%' 
  OR e.keywords LIKE '%world%'
```

Also, the use of table aliases is never a bad idea, especially if your table names are long.

Answer (score 1):

Use [LEFT JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp)s (I altered the order of your joins and fixed the where clause location, which was misplaced)

```
select * from event LEFT JOIN event_location ON 
event.event_id = event_location.event_id 
LEFT JOIN 
location ON event_location.location_id = location.location_id
where keywords like '%hello%' OR
keywords like '%world%'
```

This way you'll get NULLs for events without location.

Also, try not to use select * but name the columns you are interested in.